# Corba python integration with web service java

Tags: java, python, web-services, corba

i'm working on a project thata i need develop one web service ( in java ) that get one simple number from a Corba python implementation... how can i proceed with this??

im using omniOrb and already done the server.py that genetares one simple number!

thx a lot

Answer (score 4):

You will need a Java CORBA provider - for example IONA or JacORB.  Generate the IDL files for your python service and then use whatever IDL -> stub compiler your Java ORB provides to generate the java client-side bindings.

From there it *should* be as simple as binding to the corbaloc:// at which your python server is running and executing the remote calls from your java stubs.

Of course, CORBA being CORBA, it is likely to require the ritual sacrifice of small mammals and, possibly, lots of candles.

Comment: so, i have to take the idl and generate the stubs from him in the java side?

Comment: @Shermano - yes.  It's been a couple of (happy) years since I last had to work with CORBA, but afair there should be a tool to compile the IDL into stubs (or skeletons too if you want server side artifacts).

Comment: but the server.idl is in the server side, how can i take him ?

Comment: you do not have to do it at run time, but in compile time for java. IDL file is like shared information needed by both client and server to communicate. With dynamic languages, you can often include this information at run time, but with static ones like c or java at compile time you use some generator provided by the orb vendor to translate IDL into java stubs (and skeletons). Those stubs are then included in your client program and compiled all together.